# Correlation between constructors in Java and __init__ function in Python

Tags: java, python, oop, constructor

I was currently learning more about constructors in Java, and I found out that just like the `__init__` function in Python, constructors are functions that are called as soon as we instantiate an object of a class.

So, are both the concepts one and the same, abstractly?

Comment: They may have similar usage when you're writing your code, but Java and Python are essentially two different languages **in concept**, so apart from that similarity, everything else is pretty much different. It would be advisable for you to concentrate on these **conceptual** differences between Java and Python, rather than on semantic differences, such as constructor declaration, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are very similar things, however with at least one big difference.

- **constructor** is called **before**/while the object is being constructed
- `__init__` is called **after** the object has been constructed, so you have a valid reference to it (called `self`)

Comment: Doesn't Java allow object referencing too with it's 'this' keyword just like Python does for 'self'?

Comment: -1 A Java constructor is called with the already allocated and somewhat-initialized object as `this`. Likewise, a Python `__init__` function is called with the already allocated and somewhat-initialized object as `self`. @ManasChaturvedi You're right, it does.

Comment: `self` and `this` are slightly different. `this` is a keyword that is always available, regardless of the method's signature, and is only required to differentiate between instance variables and local/class variables with the same name. `self` (or whichever name the programmer chooses) is the first argument to a method, which Python populates with a reference to the calling object at runtime and *must* be used to access instance variables.

Comment: @chepner The syntactical constructs have different meaning, but in both cases it's a reference to the instance that's already partially allocated and is now being initialized via constructor/`__init__`. Note that if `this` was available *before* the object was created, you'd have a nasty memory safety bug: You could access uninitialized or not-even-allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is for initialisation. `__new__` is often used first.

Comment: I would probably say that `__new__` is _occasionally_ used.